# How do I get flow to correctly check the interface being implemented by a type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have flow code which looks like this. When I `flow check` I get an error `1: const docs: Array<LeadDoc> =  property docType of LeadDoc. Property not found in`

Is this not yet supported in flow?

```
export interface LeadDoc {
  docType(): string;
}

class Foo {
  docType(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

const docs: Array<LeadDoc> = [
  Foo,
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docType` is a property of *instances* of `Foo`, but `[Foo]` is the singleton array of the *statics* of `Foo`. `[new Foo]` is of the type `Array<LeadDoc>`.